# Bind DNS named.config serial- Should it autoincrement? Alternatives to ammending it each time

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, dns-zone, master-slave

I'm configuring a DNS service for the first time which involves a master DNS server and a slave DNS server. On investigating why the slave zones were not updating after I make edits to the zones on the master DNS, I discovered that the serial value in the zones (on master and slave) needs to:

(a) Be different
(b) Increment in the master zones in order for the files to be copied across.

Does this mean when a new client machine is added to the master zone files, I would always need to remember to change the serial value in each file? Or is there another solution for this which I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to increment this every time you make changes to master zone. For more info: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2182

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean when a new client machine is added to the master zone files, I would always need to remember to change the serial value in each file?

Yes the serial number must be incremented after each change to a zone.
The serial number is how slaves keep track if they need to update their cached copy of the zone, or not.